# Como verificar se o form foi enviado vazio

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida de como verificar se o form está vazio.

Minha intenção não é checar campo por campo, imaginando que eu posso ter `N³³³ campos`.

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
<form method="post" name="submit" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="input_txt"/>
    <input type="text" name="input_txt2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub_btn"/>
</form>
<?php
if(empty($_POST))
{
    echo "empty";
}else
{
    echo "no empty";
}
?>
```

Entretanto o resultado é sempre `no empty`.

Como posso resolver isso ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem. Se um campo estiver preenchido o `form` seria "válido" em sua dúvida?

Comment: Tipo assim : eu tenho `n` campos, se o cara clicar em submit direto com todos vazios, ai escreve `empty`, se tiver um campo com dados escreve `no empty`...

Comment: Não acho essa uma boa abordagem. Todavia, acho melhor deixar alguém que entende de PHP responder. Vai que existe algo que eu desconheça :p

Comment: Se tiver uma outra abordagem para verificar se o form está sendo enviado vazio, sem checar campo por campo, será bem vinda...

Comment: Acho que o melhor seria fazer assim http://stackoverflow.com/a/3190482/3228982 mas ainda assim é verificado campo a campo

Comment: @MagicHat Não sei se isso é possível. Eu sempre vi as pessoas criando uma função para verificar se o campo é null e passando um `array` com os nomes dos campos. Assim é feita a verificação dos campos desejados. Porém, desconheço algo que faça isso *automaticamente* em PHP.

Comment: @Augusto esse código do link vai verificar se existe algum campo em branco e não se todos estão em branco.

Comment: @Pagotti, sim mas pode usar a mesma ideia só alterando no `if` de `empty` para `!empty` e dar um `break`. Acho que resolveria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vale citar que utilizando `<input name="btn" type="submit" value="Enviar" />`, o valor de `btn` sempre estará presente no vetor `$_POST`, pois o PHP trata o próprio botão como uma entrada do formulário (já que é um *input*). Desta forma, para considerar apenas os campos "reais" do formulário, é preciso descartar tal valor do vetor:

```
unset($_POST["btn"]);
```

E depois verificar os valores restantes. Também é válido ressaltar que uma *string* vazia é considerada, pelo PHP, como um valor possível e, por isso, a função `empty` sempre retornará `false`, visto que o vetor possuirá elementos com valor *string* vazia. Para contornar isso, basta filtrar o vetor conforme seus valores:

```
array_filter($_POST);
```

Não passando o segundo parâmetro da função `array_filter`, serão removidos todos os valores considerados falsos e, neste caso, *string* vazia é, por padrão, considerado falso no PHP. Desta forma, restariam em `$_POST` apenas os campos devidamente preenchidos.

O código ficaria algo assim:

```
unset($_POST["sub_btn"]);

if(empty(array_filter($_POST))) {
    echo "empty";
}else {
    echo "no empty";
}
```

Comment: Muito bom...Vlw

Answer (score 3):

De uma forma bem simplificada:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="input_txt"/>
    <input type="text" name="input_txt2"/>
    <button name="sub_btn"/>Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php

$formVals = array_count_values($_POST);
$key = key($formVals);

if(count($formVals) == 1)
{
    echo "empty";
}else
{
    echo "no empty";
}
?>
```

A variável `$_POST` é um Array que, sempre que um POST é realizado recebe os valores dos campos, ou seja, utilizando `print_r($_POST)` vamos obter um resultado similar à esse:

```
Array ( [input_txt] => [input_txt2] => [sub_btn] => )
```

Como `[sub_btn]` sempre retornará `NULL` basta verificar a quantidade de valores presentes no `$_POST` utilizando [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php), se for apenas 1 valor (`count($formVals) == 1`), todos os campos estão vazios.

Comment: Muito bom man...Vlw...

Answer (score 0):

Olá Mas no caso de um Form assim que é dividido por opções ou seja só ira aparecer ao usuario se ele clicar o botão de opção pessoa fisica só os campos pessoa fisica e se for pessoa juridica só os campos pessoa juridica como faria no php a verificação de todos os camps preenchidos neste caso

```
<form action="" method="post"><div class="form-group">
      <p>
       <label class="radio-inline col-sm-4"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="juridica" onclick="pessoa(this.value);">Pessoa Juridica</label>
        <label class="radio-inline col-sm-4"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="fisica" onclick="pessoa(this.value);">Pessoa Fisica</label>
      </p>
      </div>

    <div id="juridica" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtRazaosocial">Razão Social: *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRazaosocial" name="txtRazaosocial" required value="<? echo $txtRazaosocial; ?>" >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtNomefantasia">Nome Fantasia:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNomefantasia" name="txtNomefantasia" value="<? echo $txtNomefantasia; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtCnpj">CNPJ: *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="numbe" class="form-control cnpj" id="txtCnpj" name="txtCnpj" required value="<? echo $txtCnpj; ?>">
        </div>

        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="txtIe">I.E.: * </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ie" id="txtIe" name="txtIe" required value="<? echo $txtIe; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="fisica" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtNomePF">Nome: *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNomePF" required name="txtNomePF" value="<? echo $txtNomePF; ?>"><? echo $msgcamponomePF; ?>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtCPF">CPF: *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="numbe" class="form-control cpf" id="txtCPF" name="txtCPF" required value="<? echo $txtCPF; ?>"><? echo $msgcampoCPF;?> <? echo $msgcpf; ?>
        </div>

        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="txtRG">RG:  </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control rg" id="txtRG" name="txtRG"  value="<? echo $txtRG; ?>" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)"><? echo $msgcampoRG; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div><table width="814" border="0" cellspacing="0">
```

no aguardo e desde já agradeço